# Unable to generate cloud end point client library

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm building an app that uses GAE using [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial) and I'm trying to generate a Cloud end point library for a class as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial#ecdp).

However, I'm getting an unexpected error. Here are the details:

```
eclipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error
Thu Jun 05 20:24:00 IST 2014
Unexpected Exception

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at     com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApi    Action.java:82)
    at     org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.google.api.server.spi.tools.ClientLibGenerator$Language
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:113)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
... 1 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.google.api.server.spi.tools.ClientLibGenerator$Language
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:113)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Eclipse version I'm using is 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. But, I have found this link and I think it can help:
http://mall.51zks.com/Problem/index/-190279264/generating-the-api-metadata-for-cloud-endpoints-classes-failed/

It basically links forward to this link, which tells how to create the endpoint library using command line too:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool

I am working on this solution now. If I get any good news, I will update.

Comment: Well, I did succeeded in generating the endpoint client library using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

As described in Google bugtracker this is a known bug, you must either downgrade to 1.9.3 or upgrade plugin tools to 3.6.0
see: https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=278